# Dictionary: Check if each element of key & value is equal or not

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

So I've extracted the source of a html and converted everything into a big dictionary.

This is only an example:

```
d = {fist:mist}
```

My goal is to compare the characters by their indexes:

```
(key[0] & value[0], key[1] & value[1], etc.)
```

and check if the characters are equal:

```
f != m, i == i, s==s, t==t
```

The best I could do:

```
d = {fist:mist}

difference = 0 
no_difference = 0

for key, value in d.items():
      for char1 in key:
          pass
      for char2 in value:
          pass
      if char1 != char2:
         difference += 1
      if char1 == char2:
         no_difference +=1

 print(difference)
 print(no_difference)
```

I appreciate any help.

Edit: Big thanks to Glenn Codes, Joe Iddon and Mike Müller!

Comment: what do you want your output to be? Number of total difference? True/False if *everything* was the same? Or something else...

Comment: What is your desired output for this example dict: `d = {'fist': 'mist', 'fist1': 'mist22', 'x': 'many differences here'}`?

Comment: @MikeMüller No, the goal is to evaluate the differences for each key:value pair. I will extract each key:value to a new dictionary and check for the differences separately (I know that seems a little overcomplicating)

Comment: But what if the lengths of key and value are different? E.g. `{'long key with lots of characters': 'short value'}`

Comment: @MikeMüller: Glenn and Joe answered that. I haven't reached that part yet, but when I do, I will write what I did!

Comment: @MikeMüller: Yes, you're right. I've gotten an IndexError as well. Gonna write more to your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop through the `key : value` pairs in the dictionary. For each pair, you need to work out how many differences there are between the `key` and the `value`. This can be done by working out the length of a `list` that only contains characters which are different.

We then just add this length to a variable outside the loop to keep track of the total.

```
d = {"fist":"mist"}
differences = 0
for k, v in d.items():
    differences += len([i for i,c in enumerate(k) if c != v[i]])

print(differences)
```

which, for the small example here, gives `1` as the `'f'` and `'m'` are different.

---

If you also want a count of the number of characters which matches (i.e. not different), then you can just do the same process but add the length of the `key` minus the differences to get the number of characters which were the same:

```
d = {"fist":"mist"}
differences = 0
same = 0
for k, v in d.items():
    differences += len([i for i,c in enumerate(k) if c != v[i]])
    same += len(k) - differences

print(differences)
print(same)
```

which again gives `differences` as `1`, but also gives `same` as `3` (for `'i'`, `'s'` and `'t'`).

---

If you just wanted a boolean (`True / False`) value for whether there are any differences between *any* of the pairs, you can do the whole operation in one line:

```
all(k == v for k,v in d.items())
```

which gives `False` in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Miggl Please accept the answer to show your appreciation (grey --> green tick next to answer).

Comment: `d = {"fist27":"mist"}` gives me an `IndexError`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming key and value will be the same length you can do:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    for i in range(len(key)):
        if key[i] == value[i]:
           no_difference +=1
        else:
           difference += 1
```

Comment: You don't actually need to keep track of both `no_difference` and `difference` as you can calculate one from the other using the length of the key/value but this solution comes closest to what you already had.

Comment: Key and value aren't always the same length but that helped, thank you!

Comment: Ah you can then simply use the length of whatever is shortest, key or value, as range. A good way to go would then be to simply keep track of the occurrences that do match. (`no_difference` in this case) `difference` would then automatically be the length of what is longest, again key or value, subtracted by the value of `no_difference`. In the case of `fist` and `misty`, `no_difference` would become 3 and `difference` would become 2 as we subtract `no_difference` from the length of `misty` which is 5 - 3 = 2.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a dictionary with multiple items and possible different lengths of keys and values, this should work:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

d = {'fist': 'mist', 'fist1': 'mist22', 'x': 'many differences here'}

difference = 0 
no_difference = 0

for k, v in d.items():
    for item1, item2 in zip_longest(k, v, fillvalue=''):
        if item1 == item2:
            no_difference += 1
        else:
            difference += 1

print('difference:', difference)
print('no_difference:', no_difference)
```

Output:

```
difference: 25
no_difference: 6
```

Comment: Thanks again for commenting! I've tried implementing your solution both into a function and externally. Externally it seems to work, but it prints too many differences. In the function, it returns None. I've got a huge headache because of that, gonna take a break and then try tomorrow again. Thanks for your time!